# How can i make a relationship between my three Models where Distributor and Product model are directly connected with the Distributorproduct Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

Distributor Table - id
Product Table - id
Distributorprocuct Table - distributor_id, product_id

Distributor Model -

```
public function product() { return $this->hasMany(Distributorproduct::class); }
```

Product Model -

```
public function distributor() { return $this->hasMany(Distributorproduct::class); }
```

Distributorproduct Model -

```
public function distributor() { return $this->belongsTo(Distributor::class); }

public function product() { return $this->belongsTo(Product::class); }
```

If I write `$product->distributor` then it gives me all the details of distributorproduct but i need the details of distributor not distributorproduct .

If i write `$distributor->product` then it gives me all the details of distributorproduct but i need the details of product not distributorproduct .

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what is the relationship between Product, DistributorProduct and Distributor, but I think what you want is to specify a different kind of relationship between Distributor and Product (and Product -> Distributor). 
In your Distributor modal class you can try defining your product method like this:

```php
public function product() { 
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Product::class, Distributorproduct::class); 
}
```

and the distributor method in the Product modal class like this:

```php
public function distributor() { 
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Distributor::class, Distributorproduct::class); 
}
```

But your mileage may vary, this kind of relationship is ok only if a Product has a single distributor (likely), and a distributor has a single Product (unlikely I guess).

The Laravel docs have a pretty good documentation about [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through). Looks especially at the **Has One Through** and the **Has Many Through** paragraphs.

Comment: has one through is a single way relationship if i have tables relationships like  distributor->distributorproduct (foreign key distributor_id)->product(foreign key distributorproduct_id) than it works but in my case i cannot store the primary key of distributorproduct_id in product table so if use hasOneThrough generates sql query error....